# Do NFAs with $\varepsilon$-moves never terminate?

Tags: computability, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Suppose in an NFA we have an $\varepsilon$-move from a state $q_0$ to $q_1$. According to Sipser,

> Without reading any input, the machine splits into multiple copies one following each of the exiting $\varepsilon$-arrows and one staying at the current state. Then the machine proceeds nondeterministically as before.

Here is an application of this logic to our case: upon reaching the state $q_0$ our machine splits into two copies: one in state $q_1$, one in state $q_0$. For the latter copy, execution continues as before, so again another copy of the machine is created in state $q_0$. Thus, a copy of the machine always in state $q_0$ will exist indefinitely.

Is this true? If no, why not? How should I then interpret the description given above?

Comment: I don't find Sipser's explanation helpful. There is no splitting; there is not really a good "executionst" intuition for non-deterministic automata. Check the definition: it's about whether an accepting computation *exists*.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for your comment! Would you mind offering a brief explanation why the splitting/forking interpretation/intuition is not a good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sipser proposes an operational intuition for non-determinstic machines. As you have experienced, it's not very useful. In particular, it doesn't relate a lot to the formal definition, and there are more problems down the road¹.

I recommend sticking to the definition: an NFA accepts an input if there is a path from a starting to a final state labelled with the input. That really tells you all you need to know, and all there *is* to know.

Try to think mathematically instead of computationally.

---

1. Parallelism and non-determinism are not the same; you can not *build* non-deterministic machines in a meaningful sense; cost models (e.g. in complexity theory) for non-deterministic machines don't make sense if you have the split/fork intuition; ...

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. The key to interpreting the quoted description correctly is noting that the splitting occurs **without reading any input**. So when we arrive at $q_0$, we split into two copies with the same input string left to be read, one in the state $q_0$, the other in the state $q_1$.

After the splitting, however, we have to continue reading the input string. 
So if $q_0$ does not have any other moves from it, the computation is simply stuck at $q_0$ and that branch of computation dies.